# Change tab items location in WPF Tab Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, tabcontrol

I want to change the TabItems Location in the WPF TabControl. 
I know there is a Property "Tab strip placement" but this one lets me only the "top", "left", "right", "bottom" options.
I want to put the tab strip inside the tab control, in the top of it, like this:

```
 -----------------------------------
 |                                 |
 |   TabItem1       TabItem2       |
 |                                 |
 |                                 |
 |                                 |
```

But I couldn't find how to do it.

The TabItems still need to switch between different contents.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by overriding the default template of tabControl which you can get from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I modified bit of the template as per you needs -

```
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabControl}}">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <Border Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           BorderThickness="1">
                      <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                                IsItemsHost="True"
                                Margin="0,10,0,0"
                                Panel.ZIndex="1"
                                KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                                Background="Transparent" />
                   </Border>
                  <Border x:Name="Border"
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          BorderThickness="1"
                          KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                          KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                          KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"
                          Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                      Margin="4"
                                      ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                  </Border>
                </Grid>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Put this style in your Window Resources and you are good to go. It gives me this look (hope this is what you want) -

[image]